# Can someone tell me and show me the exact files i need for rails jquery autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

Ive been at this for hours and i am still unable to get [jquery autocomplete](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) to work even after following the examples on here and the examples on github. What are the exact files i am suppose to use because i set everything up, routes are correct, seed and still get no jquery autocomplete, the textbox not doing anything.

Here are the files i am using right now:

```
autocomplete-rails.js
jquery.js
jquery.min.js
jquery_ujs.js
jquery-ui.js
jquery-ui.min.js
```

Something doesn't look right, has anyone done this before, what files do you have?

**EDIT, UPDATED AND WORKING:**

Make sure you have the correct files AND put the images inside of the public/images folder.

```
jquery.js
jquery_ujs.js
jquery-ui.js
rails.js
autocomplete-rails.js
application.js
```

and then have my custom theme:

```
jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails3 project with jquery need below, and you can check out in `config/application.rb`

```
jquery.js
rails.js
```

And using autocomplete, you need:

```
jquery-ui.min.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snipit of jquery code that's working for me:

```
$.getJSON("/polymerases.json",function(polsFromServer){
    pols = polsFromServer;
    $(#polymerases).autocomplete({
        source: pols
    });
});
```

here's my controller code:

```
@polymerases = Polymerase.all
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @polymerases }
  format.json do
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "public, max-age=60"
    render :json => @polymerases.map(&:formatted_name).to_json
  end
end
```

I'm including 'jquery-1.5.2.min.js', 'jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js'
as well as my local js file (see above) that does the .autocomplete call to bind up the autocomplete functionality to the selected input box.

I think you don't need the non minified versions of jquery and jquery-ui.
I'm not familiar with the _ujs or autocomlete-rails bits.

If you're not using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or chrome's developer mode to step through your javascript, I strongly recommend you do that.

Also, it might help to look at your raw json data (eg: http://localhost:3000/polymerases.json)